# Django queryset.update() seems to act lazy

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a Django model with a field named `order` :

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(...)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [
            ['user', 'order'],
        ]

    def set_order(self, order):
        self.order = order
        self.save()
```

I want to implement an update method for my serializer to be able to reorder an object. Let's consider our object's current order is 5 and we want to change it to 1. So the scenario is something like this:

1. make obj's current order null
2. increment order of objects that have an order between our obj's current_order and new_order
3. change obj's order to new_order

My first attempt at the code is this:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    user = self.context['request'].user
    current_order = instance.order
    new_order = validated_data['order']

    instance.set_order(None)

    if new_order < current_order:
        qs = PIN.objects.exclude(order__isnull=True).filter(
            user_id=user.id, order__gte=new_order, order__lt=current_order
        ).update(order=F('order')+1)
    else:
        qs = PIN.objects.exclude(order__isnull=True).filter(
            user_id=user.id, order__gt=current_order, order__lte=new_order
        ).update(order=F('order')-1)
```

But the problem is the order of updating objects in database and I get unique constraint error:

```
('user', 'order') = ('x', '2') already exist
```

I did read the [django documentations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update:%7E:text=method%20was%20added.-,Ordered%20queryset,-%C2%B6:%7E:text=method%20was%20added.-,Ordered,-queryset%C2%B6) for queryset.update method, so, order_by method is not the result (I'm using PostgreSQL).

I decided to change my code to this:

```
    user = self.context['request'].user
    current_order = instance.order
    new_order = validated_data['order']
    instance.set_order(None)

    if new_order < current_order:
        qs = Foo.objects.exclude(order__isnull=True).filter(
            user_id=user.id, order__gte=new_order, order__lt=current_order
        )
        qs_orders = qs.values_list('order', flat=True)
        qs_objs = list(qs)
        qs.update(order=None)           

        for idx, qs_order in enumerate(qs_orders):
            qs_objs[idx].order = qs_order + 1

        Foo.objects.bulk_update(qs_objs, ['order'])
    else:
        qs = Foo.objects.exclude(order__isnull=True).filter(
            user_id=user.id, order__gt=current_order, order__lte=new_order
        ).update(order=F('order')-1)
        qs_orders = qs.values_list('order', flat=True)
        qs_objs = list(qs)
        qs.update(order=None)           

        for idx, qs_order in enumerate(qs_orders):
            qs_objs[idx].order = qs_order - 1

        Foo.objects.bulk_update(qs_objs, ['order'])

    instance.set_order(new_order)
```

Now, when I debug the code with pycharm debug (line by line), the code works fine, but, when I run the project (like python manage.py runserver) and call the API, the unique_together constraint error appears again!

It seems that **qs.update(order=None)** is not working, or works lazy!

where is the catch?! any advice?

Comment: What is the `instance.reorder` method? Are you sure it's updating the instance and saving to the DB?

Comment: @Iian I implemented it in my django model to set an order to object without any conditions, let me update my question.

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).